# Adding knockout if statement in a cshtml razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I want to add an if statement checking on the count of users before a header title.

```
<div>
   <span  data-bind="text:Name()"></span> 
   <span class="userCount">(<span data-bind="text:UserCount()"></span>)</span>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="list">
    //Want to add if statement here to check if the UserCount() is greater than 13
    <h3 id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter"></h3>
    ......
</script>
```

How can I add an if statement to check for the usercount()?

viewModel:

```
var rViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
        _self.Name = ko.observable(data.RoleName);
        _self.Rank = ko.observable(data.RoleRank);
        _self.UserCount = ko.observable(data.UserCount);
        _self.Users = ko.observableArray([]);
    };
```

Comment: @MattBodily i am using data-binding(knockout) to get my info like Usercount and i can't do `@if(data-bind="UserCount()")`

Answer (score 3):

```
@if (Model.UserCount() > 13) {
    <h3 id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter"></h3>
}
```

Comment: for me the Model.UserCount() won't work because I am doing a `foreach:Titles` and then within it i am doing a bind on `text:UserCount()`. and i tried `Model.Titles.UserCount()` but didn't compile.

Comment: Html content is commonly placed in script tags for client side templating purposes.  Note the type in  `<script type="text/html" id="list">`.

Comment: Masriyah, can you please post more of your code in that case including the foreach? JayC, Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

because you are inside the list, the context is the list. you need to access your parent viewModel like this:

```
$parent.UserCount() > 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your knockout model, you should be able to do something like this

```
<!-- ko if: Users().count > 13 -->
    <h3 id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter"></h3>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: i added the viewModel in which i have the userCount - not sure if another piece would be needed but i like this approach and will give it a try

Comment: this is the error message i am getting: `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: UserCount is not defined;
Bindings value: if: UserCount() > 13`

Comment: @Masriyah, based on the HTML you are showing you are not binding to your template. Can you set the whole thing up in jsfiddle so I can better see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

If statement in razor view.

```
@{
var a = "No";

if(a == "No")
{
//do something
}
else{
//Do something else
}

}
```

Comment: the question is how to add a knockout if statement which this isnt